# Linux and Windows domains

Tags: samba, domain, smb

How can I get the Windows domain toward which the instance of smbd (version 3.X) is currently connected?

How can I say if the instance running on this Linux is the Domain controller?

I browse the Internet, and am i stupid or not, i cannot grasp one site which show a simple command to do so.

As i am the Linux administrator, i am not supposed to have an access to the Windows domain.  I would like to avoid breaking the security (lol).  On the Internet, i always need to use the SMB protocol to do so.

Answer (score 0):

For Samba 3 the configuration file at `/etc/samba/smb.conf` will show you the domain to which your system is joined.

The relevant keyword entries are

```
netbios name SERVER_NAME    # This system's name as shown to Windows hosts
server string = My server   # Description of this system

workgroup ADEXAMPLE         # Short domain name
realm ad.example.net        # Long (fully qualified) domain name
```

I've never set up any of my Linux-based systems as a Domain Controller so I cannot answer your second part of question from first-hand experience. However,
according to the [man page for `smb.conf`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html), the entry `domain logons = yes` enables the Domain Controller component of Samba.